# KnockoutJS: Determining when changes to "ko.observableCollection" have finished rendering/updating the view

Tags: knockout.js

I have an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ncortines/p6p9r/13/) in which I render a list of items using KnockoutJS.

Every time a new item is added or removed to the ko.observableCollection a function is automatically triggered to reset all the item positions.

In order to achieve this I subscribe to the ko.observableCollection to trigger the "reArrangeTiles" function:

```
this.reArrangeTiles = function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        self.$('.grid').each(function () {
            self.$('.tile[tileid=' + $(this).attr('tileid') + ']').animate($(this).position(), {duration: 500, queue: false});
        });
    }, 500);
};
```

Each item in the ko.observableCollection is rendered twice, as "float:left" and "position:absolute". The "float:left" is invisible and its purpose is to mark the position where the "position:absolute" item needs to be moved to.

The problem is that I need to wrap the re-arrange logic in a 500ms timeout because I need to wait for KnockoutJS to finish rendering the changes before I can obtain the updated positions.

Does somebody know a better way to handle this than using a timeout?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out.

Using "afterAdd" and "beforeRemove" callbacks I can trigger the "reArrangeTiles" at the appropriate moment.

Important note here is that when "beforeRemove" binding is used, the corresponding node needs to be explicitly removed. Once the node is removed I can invoke the "reArrangeTiles" function:

```
this.hideTile = function (elem) {
    if (elem.nodeType === 1) {
        $(elem).fadeOut(function () {
            $(elem).remove();
            self.reArrangeTiles();
        });
    }
};
```

Updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ncortines/p6p9r/27/)